# SQL Server query performance alternative (Concatenating strings in LIKE statemen)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have one performance issue on a huge SQL Server table. We have this query:

```
    SELECT cycle
       FROM   product AS pr
       INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd
           ON prd.label = 'XRT354511' 
           AND ( pr.cycle = prd.cycle OR prd.cycle LIKE pr.cycle+ '-EXECUTED%' )
```

Condition after OR statement is using like to concatenate product table cycle with -EXECUTED (We don't care about the '-EXECUTED' position in cycle, we just need to know if the cycle contains -EXECUTED).

Then, my proposal to fix this issue is change that query for this one:

```
SELECT cycle
   FROM   product AS pr
   INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd
       ON prd.label = 'XRT354511' 
       AND ( pr.cycle = prd.cycle
          OR (pr.cycle = prd.cycle AND pr.cycle LIKE '-EXECUTED%'))
```

When i executed second query, it runs pretty fast and smooth.

Is my proposal valid, Can i use my proposal and get the same results than first query?

Thanks

Comment: The logic looks different to me.  Maybe you should include some actual data so we can see how to improve the first query.  If the second query returns identical results and performs better, then of course use it.

Comment: These queries will return two different results

Comment: Are you sure the query returns same result set? I'd be very careful with brackets and AND/OR operator.

Comment: The second query requires pr.cycle = prd.cycle and the first one does not.

Comment: have you solved? have you found any answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

Could you change `OR` part with this one?

```
OR (pr.cycle = LEFT(prd.cycle, LEN(pr.cycle)) AND prd.cycle LIKE '%-EXECUTED%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question: "Is my proposal valid, Can i use my proposal and get the same results than first query?"

No, they are not the same.
Let's rewrite your two queries in following way, so we can concentrate on join condition:

```
SELECT cycle
FROM   product AS pr
INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd ON  pr.cycle = prd.cycle OR prd.cycle LIKE pr.cycle+ '-EXECUTED%'
WHERE prd.label = 'XRT354511' ;
```

and

```
SELECT cycle
FROM   product AS pr
INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd ON  pr.cycle = prd.cycle
      OR (pr.cycle = prd.cycle AND pr.cycle LIKE '-EXECUTED%')
WHERE prd.label = 'XRT354511' ;
```

The first condition is

```
pr.cycle = prd.cycle OR prd.cycle LIKE pr.cycle+ '-EXECUTED%'
```

The second (your proposal) is

```
  pr.cycle = prd.cycle
    OR (pr.cycle = prd.cycle AND pr.cycle LIKE '-EXECUTED%')
```

This latter is equivalent to

```
 pr.cycle = prd.cycle OR pr.cycle LIKE '-EXECUTED%
```

As you can see easily in this simplified form, in the first you look for (eg. if pr.cycle='100') '100'  and '100-EXECUTED%'.  In the latter you look for '100' (or pr.cycle LIKE 'EXECUTED%')

If you post sample data, I can try to see results with you and try analyze performances.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your 1st question is NO, your solution will get diiferent results than original query

to optimize the query you should analyze which indexes are active on your product and productdetails tables..

you can try;

```
SELECT cycle
FROM product AS pr
INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd ON pr.cycle = prd.cycle 
WHERE prd.label = 'XRT354511' 

UNION ALL

SELECT cycle
FROM product AS pr
INNER JOIN productdetails AS prd 
ON  SUBSTRING(prd.cycle, 1, LEN(pr.cycle)+9) COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN = (pr.cycle + '-EXECUTED') COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN
WHERE prd.label = 'XRT354511' 
AND pr.cycle <> prd.cycle
```

This will split it in two queries, the 1st will probably use an index and the 2nd should be slight fast then the like operator

But you also told that the position of `"-EXECUTED"` should not be important in `productdetails.cycle`

In this case you need to change the 2nd join condition to

```
ON  prd.cycle COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN LIKE (pr.cycle + '-%-EXECUTED%') COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN
```

please note the `"-%"` **before** `"-EXECUTED"`

also note the last condition of 2nd query, you COULD try to change the `UNION ALL` with a simple `UNION` and remove `AND pr.cycle <> prd.cycle`